# Proving all finite subsets of real numbers is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show all finite subsets of reals is uncountably infinite (or is it?).

Firstly, I assumed that "all finite subsets of reals" is equivalent to the Kleene closure of  $\mathbb{R}$,  $$\mathbb{R}^* =  \mathbb{R}^0\cup\mathbb{R}^1\cup\mathbb{R}^2\cup...$$

- $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. $\Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$ is uncountable.
- $\mathbb{R}^1 \subset  \mathbb{R}^* \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^*$ is uncountable because the union of an uncountable set with another set is also uncountable.
- $\mathbb{R}^*$ is uncountably infinite.

Is this a valid proof? I am sort of new to the subject of proofs..

Comment: This is valid, provided you replace $\mathbb R^1\in\mathbb R^*$ by $\mathbb R^1\subset\mathbb R^*$.

Comment: I see, that is clearer.

Comment: Not clearer, true instead of false.

Comment: Is it because $\mathbb{R}^1$ is not an element?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^1$ is not an element of $\mathbb{R}^*$ as it is not finite.  But it is a subset.

Comment: In general, $A\cup B=C\implies A\subset C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$ Singletons are finite subsets. How many singleton subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are there?

---

The Kleene closure is a way of computing all the finite subsets but introducing it is not exactly necessary since the main idea really is $\mathbb{R}^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^*$, which is exactly the hint.

Comment: That proves the bullet "$\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$ is uncountable" but I think James already knew that.